# Using const references as lvalues

Tags: c++, reference

A few examples:

```cpp
const char* chars = returnschars();

const std::string str(chars);
const std::string& str_ref(chars);
```

Is there a difference between `str` and `str_ref` and what exactly is different?

```cpp
const auto& foo = createfoo();
const auto& bar = createbarbasedonfoo(foo)
const auto& pair = std::make_pair(foo, bar);
```

Why does this work?
Who owns the object that `foo` is referencing?

```cpp
const int& i = 15;
const int j = 15;
```

Again, is there a difference between `i` and `j` and what exactly is different?

Could I just only use const references instead of const?

Comment: It seems like you're asking about temporary lifetime extension

Comment: `const auto& wrapper = wrapper(foo);` should not compile.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks, I'll have to do some reading and playing around, but that looks like the right place.

Comment: @appleapple
What I did was 

```const auto& foo = create_foo();
const auto& bar = create_bar_based_on_foo(foo);
const auto& baz = std::make_pair(foo, bar);
```

Comment: @Rasmus-123 you can [edit] the post to correct the information.